# I can't run more then two task in ported freeRtos for AtMega328p controller for custom board

Tags: rtos, freertos

i have use Atmega328p  controller and programming by eclipse AVR gcc tool chain setup.. now, i was make my Rtos code by change source file of freeRTOS.org websites.. now i can't run more then two task.. so, give me proper solution for that.. i was created my setup as per denoted in below link...
http://codeintherightway.blogspot.in/2015/06/freertos-on-arduino-uno-using-eclipse.html

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  If you've tried to implement something and it doesn't work then post a [minimum, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.  If you don't know how to implement something then explain in more detail where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

By "can't run more than two tasks" do you mean the first two calls to xTaskCreate() succeed, but further calls to xTaskCreate() fail?  If so then you have simple run out of heap space and the following page will help: http://www.freertos.org/a00111.html